# Sequelize trying to SELECT a column which doesn't exist of a join table

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I'm having trouble querying a join table. I use, for example, the findAll() Model method. It gives me this error

code:

```
const { UserItems, sequelize } = require('./dbObjects');
const { Op } = require('sequelize');

async function run() {
    const userItem = await UserItems.findAll();
    console.log(user);
}

run();
```

error:

```
    at async Function.findAll (E:\1dsktp\bot\node_modules\sequelize\dist\lib\model.js:1119:21)
    at async run (E:\1dsktp\bot\dbTesting.js:14:15) {
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  parent: [Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: id] {
    errno: 1,
    code: 'SQLITE_ERROR',
    sql: 'SELECT `id`, `amount` FROM `userItems` AS `userItems`;'
  },
  original: [Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: id] {
    errno: 1,
    code: 'SQLITE_ERROR',
    sql: 'SELECT `id`, `amount` FROM `userItems` AS `userItems`;'
  },
  sql: 'SELECT `id`, `amount` FROM `userItems` AS `userItems`;',
  parameters: {}
}
```

For some reason, It's trying to look for a column named 'id', which of course doesn't exist.

My db is pretty simple, it consists of 3 tables, one being a join table:

- User
- Item
- UserItems (join table and the one I'm having trouble with)

**UserItems** has two foreign keys, which are `userId` from **User** and `itemId` from **Item**. These were added associating both tables with the belongsToMany() method.

```
User.belongsToMany(Item, { through: UserItems, foreignKey: 'userId' });
Item.belongsToMany(User, { through: UserItems, foreignKey: 'itemId' });
```

[Here is a picture of what the UserItems table looks like (I'm using SQLiteStudio for this)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siDBW.png)

Here is the **UserItems** model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const model = sequelize.define('userItems', {
        amount: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            defaultValue: 0,
            allowNull: false,
        },
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
    });
    return model;
};
```

Comment: Please add `UserItems` model definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you need to add a primary key column for `UserItems` (both in a table and in a model) because Sequelize does not support composite primary and foreign keys and by default, it suggests you have `id` as a primary key if you don't define any primary key explicitly.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been following tutorials over YouTube where they declared those foreign keys **only** with associations. I solved it setting two attributes (userId and itemId) as primary keys, and then making the association.